# Tomcat multiple services - startup problems

Tags: tomcat, basex

I'm trying to run two instances of BaseX in Tomcat with the following server.conf. I'm running into an odd problem: both  are available on their respective ports, but the webapp itself is the same WAR; i.e. a link that is *only* in the webapps/ WAR appears in the WAR loaded from webapps2. I'm not really sure what my next steps should be -- I'll ask on the BaseX mailing list but they're not using much Tomcat there.

Here's my server.conf

```
<Service name="Catalina">
  <Connector port="8080"
             protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             redirectPort="8443"/>
  <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
  <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
     </Realm>
     <Host name="localhost"
           appBase="webapps"
           unpackWARs="true"
           autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log."
               suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &#34;%r&#34; %s %b"/>
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="Catalina2">
  <Connector port="18080"
             protocol="HTTP/1.1"
             connectionTimeout="20000"
             redirectPort="18443"/>
  <Connector port="18009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="18443"/>
  <Engine name="Catalina2" defaultHost="localhost">
     <Host name="localhost"
           appBase="webapps2"
           unpackWARS="true"
           autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
               directory="logs2"
               prefix="localhost_Cat2_access_log."
               suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &amp;quot;%r&amp;quot; %s %b"/>
     </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

When I start Tomcat, everything in both services loads okay except for the second BaseX application. When Tomcat starts to load that I get the following error:

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina2
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-     7.0.53/webapps2/bX79.war
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /bX79 threw load() exception
  java.net.BindException: Address already in use
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
  at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:330)
  at org.basex.BaseXServer.<init>(BaseXServer.java:110)
  at org.basex.http.HTTPContext.init(HTTPContext.java:379)
  at org.basex.http.BaseXServlet.init(BaseXServlet.java:34)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 03, 2014 7:59:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps2/examples
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@25288684')
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps2/docs
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps2/ROOT
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps2/manager
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/home/cob/src/apache-tomcat-7.0.53/webapps2/host-manager
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-18080"]
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-18009"]
Nov 03, 2014 7:59:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8304 ms
```

I'm not really sure that port is that's causing the problem. `netstat` and grepping for other ports in use aren't returning anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Basex mailing list guy, I don't have much knowledge about Tomcat... However, the error message you get is quite well-known to me. It would be useful to see your `.basex` (or any other place, where you define your BaseX options). I would guess you modified the Server port for both instances to point to different ports.

However, you did not modify the [Event port](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#EVENTPORT), thus the server does not start up correctly. Try modifying it to use some other port.